# Changing default desktop environment

Tags: fedora, desktop-environment

I'm on Fedora 20 and I want to change the default desktop environment from Gnome3 to Gnome classic. I want to do this with the terminal because I can't access the dropdown menu on the login screen (Once I select a user it logs straight in).

I already installed it, all I have need to do now is switch from Gnome3 to Gnome Classic.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but if you are thinking of switching to Gnome Classic, you may want to look at MATE too and then decide which you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the requirement for entering password on login will give you an opportunity to select the desktop environment in `gdm`.

User account management will let you enable the option you need for that.

You could also edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to force a new default choice, but I don't know which settings to add there (`man gdm` might help with that).

Answer (score 0):

See the `switchdesk` tool.  It alters your `.Xclients`.